# mysql - why sql query is selecting unnecessary values?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I want to select rows where the condition is true. I have a column named `command`, and if the column value contains defined (by me) strings, than add to result.

My problem is selecting the rows, because the query doesn't see the WHERE statement, it selects all the data if the column `command` contains the string.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `admin_log` 
WHERE `admin_log`.`user` = 'Admin' 
    AND command LIKE '%aznot%' 
    OR command LIKE '%hango%' 
ORDER BY `order_id` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

For example, I have 3 administrator accounts: Admin, Zuppa, Grund. I want to select all the data by account ADMIN if the command column contain: aznot or hango.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With this query what exactly is returned.

Comment: What sort of results are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You need some parenthesis.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `admin_log`
WHERE `admin_log`.`user` = 'Admin'  
AND (command LIKE '%aznot%' OR command LIKE '%hango%')
ORDER BY `order_id` 
DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `admin_log` WHERE `admin_log`.`user` = 'Admin' 
 AND (command LIKE '%aznot%' OR command LIKE '%hango%') 
 ORDER BY `order_id` DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `admin_log` WHERE `admin_log`.`user` = 'Admin' AND (command LIKE '%aznot%' OR command LIKE '%hango%') ORDER BY `order_id` DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better practice to separate the OR statements into a separate expression, to prevent misinterpretation by the engine.

```
SELECT * FROM `admin_log` WHERE `admin_log`.`user` = 'Admin' AND (command LIKE '%aznot%' OR command LIKE '%hango%') ORDER BY `order_id` DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `admin_log` 
WHERE  `admin_log`.`user` = 'Admin' 
       AND (command LIKE '%aznot%'
        OR command LIKE '%hango%' )
ORDER  BY `order_id` DESC 
LIMIT  0, 50
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to properly nest the conditions. see the precedence rules for logical operators in SQL